# Writing formatted XML with XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, xmlwriter, xml-formatting

I'm trying to write to an XML file to the isolated storage but I would like to format it like this:-

```
<SampleData>
  <Item Property1="AliquaXX" />
  <Item Property1="Integer" />
  <Item Property1="Quisque" />
  <Item Property1="Aenean" />
  <Item Property1="Mauris" />
  <Item Property1="Vivamus" />
  <Item Property1="Nullam" />
  <Item Property1="Nam" />
  <Item Property1="Sed" />
  <Item Property1="Class" />
</SampleData>
```

but I'm buggered if I can work it out, can anyone help?

Comment: What code do you have and what is its output?

Comment: curious why you want to write xml to isolated storage instead of storing just the values and creating the XML on the fly?

Comment: Did you ever get things figured out?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can customize the xml output via the [XmlWriterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx).

You didn't include any code, but you can set the XmlWriterSettings when you create the XmlWriter.  You can also just use something like:

```
var myXmlWriter = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
```

Comment: this is not possible since XmlWritterSettings.Ident is read-only and doing so throws an exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException'

Comment: @r1verside looks public to me:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indent(v=vs.110).aspx.  It's been awhile since I last answered this, but I'm pretty sure I ran the code myself and it worked fine.  Also note that Jon Skeet's answer similarly sets the XmlWriterSetting's Indent property.

Comment: The Settings property stays null for me. Used `new XmlTextWriter`

Comment: @r1verside Create an XmlWriterSettings before creating the writer, set the desired settings then create an XmlWriter and pass the settings, the XmlWriter accepts an XmlWriterSettings argument. I know this is an old topic but it may help other people. Yes the property Indent for example is public but it throws an exception when trying to change it.

Comment: This creates an exception:  `System.Xml.XmlException: 'The 'XmlWriterSettings.Indent' property is read only and cannot be set.'`

Answer (score 28):

I suspect you need to create an [`XmlWriterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) with the behaviour you want (indentation etc) and then pass that to the `XmlWriter` on creation. Just setting [`Indent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indent%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to true may well be enough:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(..., settings))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you're implementing your own `XmlWriter` you can do:

```cs
var myXmlWriter = new MyXmlWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};
```

or do `this.Formatting = Formatting.Indented` in it's constructor.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `DataSet.GetXML()`

```
Dim column As DataColumn
For Each column In DataSet.Tables.Item(0).Columns
    column.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute
Next
Dim xml As String = DataSet.GetXml()
```

It is not related to XmlWriter but you can use it for formatting XML.