# Flat xml file c#

Tags: c#

I'm wrting xml file with UTF-8 (without Bom) encoding as follow:

```
xmldecl.Encoding = "UTF-8";
dataDoc.InsertBefore(xmldecl, root);//dataDoc is XmlDocument object
using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(targetPath, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
{
     dataDoc.Save(writer);
}
```

My "problem" is the file is saved in one line instead of xml formatting,

I.e if i have the following xml:

```
<ElementA>
    <ElementB/>
</ElementA>
```

With my code the xml file will be:

```
<ElementA><ElementB/></ElementA>
```

Instead of xml format.

How can i solve it?

*I'm try to open the file with Notepad++

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to view the file?

Comment: @sr28 I'm using Notepad++

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing formatted XML with XmlWriter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535280/writing-formatted-xml-with-xmlwriter)

Comment: I think duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123718/format-xml-string-to-print-friendly-xml-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XmlTextWriter` has a property [`Formatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.formatting(v=vs.110).aspx) to define the way the output is written:

```
using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(targetPath, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
{
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    dataDoc.Save(writer);
}
```